# Reading files from python and adding to a list with correct value type

Tags: python, list

I am reading a file in python and i need to add every line to a list. The problem is that every line is a list containing string and integers. This is the file i am reading:
[file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eE5f.png)

this is the output of reading the file and putting it on the new list.
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcweX.png)

as you can see it is storing me the lines as a string but it need to be like this:
[correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JurWl.png)

CODE:

```py
def build_sets(f):
   
    lista_valores = []

    with open(f, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            lista_valores += line.strip().split('\n')

    print(lista_valores)
    #pass
```

Comment: please enter current output and expected output directly into the answer - linking _PICTURES_ of them is just making it harder for anyone to help you. Also, if you made this into a full working example, it would, again, be easier for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your `for` loop:

```
lista_valores = line.strip('][').split(', ')
```

Also please only use english words to define your variables, it's one of the main rules of variable naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Use ast.literal_eval with which you can safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. Hence it will evluate your string as a proper list.

```
import ast

def build_sets(f):
    lista_valores = []
    with open(f, "r") as f:
      a = f.read().splitlines()

    for item in a:
      lista_valores.append(ast.literal_eval(item))
    print(lista_valores)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 'a', 'b'], [2, 'b', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys, i figured it out this way:
lista_valores = []

```
with open(f, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        linha = line[0:len(line)-1].strip("[]").split(',')
        lista_valores.append(linha)


for i in range(len(lista_valores)): # convert to int
    for j in range(len(lista_valores[i])):
        if lista_valores[i][j].isdigit():
            lista_valores[i][j] = int(lista_valores[i][j])
```